# Mocha, CoffeeScript, ZombieJS, Timout?

Tags: node.js, timeout, coffeescript, mocha.js, zombie.js

I've came across a weird problem, and I cannot figure out why it's doing it.

I'm using express-coffeescript as the framework, mocha for testing along with should, chai, and zombiejs for the browser testing.

```
 request = require 'request'
 Browser = require 'zombie'
 assert  = require 'assert'
 chai    = require 'chai'  
 should  = require 'should'
 expect  = chai.expect
 chai.should

 browser = new Browser()

 describe 'GET /login', ->

    it 'should login a user successfully', (done) ->
        browser.on "error", -> 
             console.log "Error"

        browser.visit "http://localhost/test-laravel/public/login",  (browser),  ->

             browser.fill "username", "TheHydroImpulse"
             browser.fill "password", "SomePassword123"
             browser.pressButton "login", ->
                  console.log browser.location.pathname
                  should.equal "randomTextHere", "/test-laravel/public/dashboard"
```

This code works perfectly fine, the test fails of course when running

```
mocha test --compilers coffee:coffee-script -R spec
```

The weird thing about this or the problem is when I make the test pass.

```
should.equal "/test-laravel/public/dashboard", "/test-laravel/public/dashboard"
```

The test should pass, but instead it hangs for a couple seconds than fails because of the timeout of 2000ms. I tried searching around but there doesn't seem to be anything documenting this problem, or maybe it's my own fault. I did just start learning coffee-script a few hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line:

```
should.equal "/test-laravel/public/dashboard", "/test-laravel/public/dashboard"
```

call the method:

```
done()
```

Doing this signals to mocha that the test has finished. This must happen because of the asynchronous nature of most code written on the Node.js platform.

Comment: A simple solution. Thank you!